Fantasy animated movie - a witch inside a bucket, brave bears, strange magic
My friend is looking for a 2D animated movie about a villain inside a water bucket carried by a dog or a wolf that he watched around 2013-2015. He doesn't have much memory of it but he watched it on an Arabic kids channel, so it was dubbed and we are sure that it was released between 2000 and 2012.
This movie is set in a world of animals and the humans of that world are some type of bear or koala or maybe pandas, they can speak like humans can  but they don't understand the speech of other animals (because they're supposed to be animals).
The elder from their community is missing or maybe dead, the bears don't know where he is but there is a painting of him. The main villain of this story is a witch who put a curse on the other animals so their speech is incomprehensible and she put a curse on the elder so that he is stuck inside a painting.
The witch doesn't have a body (she lost it because of a curse maybe?) but she is actually the form of water and is carried around in a water bucket by a dog and resides in an abandoned cave.
The bears set out on a journey to find the witch and defeat her and in the end the curse is broken by the creatures placing their hands (or their paws) on handmarks. Then the people inside the painting are free and the other animals can now talk - and the dog abandons the witch and he kicks over her bucket which spills the water.

I found a reddit post obviously describing watching the same movie dubbed in Arabic. https://www.reddit.com/r/whatsthemoviecalled/comments/1bsaulv/a_movie_about_a_villain_inside_water_bucket/

The reddit poster remembered a few more details. Should I edit them into the question or quote them in a 'answer'?

@JudithJones good spot, definitely the same question. OP on reddit said that the movie is NOT: "Legend of a Rabbit: The Martial of Fire", "Haunted Village" (1997), "Bamse i Trollskogen", "Brichos" (2007) and "Brichos: A floresta de nosta" (2012)

OK. Have you other idea? It could be an anime too.

@JudithJones Perhaps it is Chinese anime "Jinjgu Mao" from 2015? Main characters are cats, but they are similar to bears or pandas - Chinese anime aren't too popular abroad, but it was translated to Arabic too. I think that cartoon is very unpopular - nobody from my Czech and Polish friends doesn't know nothing similar and my American friends too. I will speak with my friend to confirm this.
